# Laravel показывать сайт только после авторизации

Tags: laravel

Как в laravel показывать сайт только после авторизации?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы конкретно имеете ввиду авторизацию (не аутентификацию), то это означает, что вам необходимо разделить полномочия у пользователей на выполнение некоторых действий.

Сделать это можно различными способами:

- Использовать gate
- Использовать gate с policies
- Использовать guard
- Использовать guard-middleware
- Или использовать различные пакеты для разделения прав у пользователей (sentry...)

Подробнее

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authorization

Answer (score 1):

В `/app/Http/routes.php` прописывать весь роутинг внутри группы с мидлваром auth

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    //ваш роутинг
});
```